# How to get error details logs in log analytics workspace for synapse analytics workspace

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse

I am creating a Power BI report to monitor performance of some azure resources. I have created an azure data factory resource and did its diagnostic setting to fetch its logs in log analytics workspace. For data factory resource I am getting error, error code and error message columns in logs of "ADFActivityRuns" logs.
Similarly I created Synapse Analytics workspace and performed pipelines and activities succeeded and failed scenarios to capture its logs, but for synapse analytics workspace, those error, error code and error message columns are not available for "SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns" logs.

I know if a pipeline fails in synapse workspace we can view its error message in monitoring section->pipeline runs->pipeline name->error column

So how can I get error details of Synapse analytics workspace (pipeline & activity fails error message) in log analytics workspace?

We wanted to create a Power BI report to provide consolidated view of the resource(like how many pipelines/ activities are failing and what is the reason for that failure). We have successfully created it for Azure data factory, But for Synapse we are not getting those errors related columns in logs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns` Logs doesn't have the `Error Details` or messages as you get in the [ADFActivityRuns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/adfactivityrun) :

[image]

But, seems there are no such columns where you can directly fetch the Error details under [SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/synapseintegrationpipelineruns) Table.

As work around, may be You can log your pipeline runs along with `Error Details` in to SQL customized and then get that data in to PowerBi.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score -1):

To add log analytics to Synapse Analytics Workspace;

- Create a Log Analytics Workspace within Azure
- Go to Synapse Workspace
- Select Diagnostic Settings

[image: Diagnostic Settings]

- Add Diagnostic Setting
- Select the logs you wish to record along with your Log Analytics Workspace that you wish to record them into and give the diagnostic a name
  [image]
- Your Log Analytics Workspace will start building up, allowing you to query locally or allowing you to [import into Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/powerbi)